# Activate Acumatica SSO Azure

Tags: single-sign-on, acumatica

Can anybody help me with the below query, Thanks in advance

- I have an Acumatica SSO Enterprise Application and it is almost set up, but unable to identify
  how to enable/activate it to test SSO.

-> Added user in application to test.

Answer (score 0):

Have you completed the steps necessary to integrate Acumatica and Azure Active Directory Integration as listed in https://help-2021r2.acumatica.com/(W(6))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=68201e8c-05e5-42da-8028-360241a2aefe

Note that you need to first enable “Active Directory and Other External SSO” feature in the Enable/Disable Features screen.